# Refer to the __dict__ of a class's "parent" class in a classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access the **dict** of the "parent" (first in the mro) of a class, i.e. `a_dict` below:

```
class A():
    a = 1

class B(A):
    b = 2

    @classmethod
    def print_dict(cls):
        b_dict = cls.__dict__.items()
        print(b_dict)

        # The following line generates this error:
        # AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'items'
        a_dict = super(cls, cls).__dict__.items()
        print(a_dict)

foo = B()
foo.print_dict()
```

`b_dict` is printed.
`a_dict` fails. From what I have read `super` delegates methods, but in this case, it is not a method, but an attribute. I could hardcode it to be:

```
a_dict = A.__dict__.items()
```

But that defeats the purpose. How would one refer to the **dict** of a parent class?

Comment: Just the immediate parent, or everything that would exist in `C` for `class C(A): pass`? Is multiple inheritance a concern?

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate answer. I searched quite a bit but could not find answer. Using it I arrived at: [ x.__dict__ for x in cls.__mro__ if x is not object ]